# Spring3 - Autowired is not happening. The object is null

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, autowired

servlet.xml

I am using annotation instead of creating bean in XML.

And I have added the "context: annotation-config" in my XML

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.hemanths.expense.manager"/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <tx:annotation-driven/>
    <context:annotation-config />

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="configLocation" value="WEB-INF/hibernate.cfg.xml"/>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

UserDaoImpl.java

```
package com.hemanths.expense.manager.hibernate.dao.impl;

import com.hemanths.expense.manager.hibernate.dao.UserDao;
import com.hemanths.expense.manager.hibernate.entity.User;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;

@Repository
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao {
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public UserDaoImpl() {
    }

    public UserDaoImpl(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    @Override
    public void addUser(User user) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(user);
    }
}
```

UserService.java

```
package com.hemanths.expense.manager.service.impl;

import com.hemanths.expense.manager.hibernate.dao.UserDao;
import com.hemanths.expense.manager.hibernate.entity.User;
import com.hemanths.expense.manager.service.UserService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.util.List;

@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;

    public UserServiceImpl() {
    }

    public UserServiceImpl(UserDao userDao){
        this.userDao = userDao;
    }

    public void setUserDao(UserDao userDao) {
        this.userDao = userDao;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void addUser(User user) {
        userDao.addUser(user);
    }
```

UserServiceImplTest.java

```
public class UserServiceImplTest {

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @Test
    public void shouldAddUser() {
        User user = new User("firstName", "lastName", new Date(), "M", "username", "password");
        userService.addUser(user);
    }
}
```

Stacktrace

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.hemanths.expense.manager.service.impl.UserServiceImplTest.shouldAddUser(UserServiceImplTest.java:18)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runNotIgnored(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:211)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

Directory Structure

[image]

Comment: what are the packages  of each class?

Comment: Why are you creating manually two beans for `userDao` and `userService` if you plan on having them auto-detected? Or the base package for `component-scan` is not covering the packages the dao and service are in?

Comment: Since you have annotated you do not need the superflous xml definitions for the beans and update your component-scan. i.e. <context component-scan base-package="package1, package2"/> Please remove <bean id="userDao" class="com.hemanths.expense.manager.hibernate.dao.impl.UserDaoImpl" autowire="byName">
</bean>
<bean id="userService" class="com.hemanths.expense.manager.service.impl.UserServiceImpl" autowire="byName">
</bean>

Comment: Why are you using both annotation and xml config for the declaration of userDao and userService? If you put `@Repository` on UserDao, you don't need to put `<bean id="userDao" class="com.hemanths.expense.manager.hibernate.dao.impl.UserDaoImpl" autowire="byName">
</bean>` on your context file.

Comment: @AndreiStefan its covering the packages

Comment: @squallsv If i remove the beans, it throws compilation error "Could not autowire"

Comment: You have this `base-package="com.base.package"` in `component-scan` and your dao and service are under `com.hemanths.expense.manager` package. Is this correct?

Comment: @AndreiStefan I have edited the base-package. the original base-package is com.hemanths. expense.manager

Comment: I have uploaded directory structure

Comment: Post the complete stacktrace, because you haven't mentioned which autowiring is not working.

Comment: @AndreiStefan both userService and userDao is not working

Comment: @AndreiStefan Is my directory structure ok?

Comment: Remove those two bean definitions from .xml and run your app. Post here the stack trace you are getting.

Comment: `Autowired is not happening. The object is null` show the complete stacktrace of exception and add code instead of adding images..

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.hemanths.expense.manager.service.impl.UserServiceImplTest.shouldAddUser(UserServiceImplTest.java:18)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
 at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
 at

Comment: So you are using those instances in a Test. Post the source code of `UserServiceImplTest`!

Comment: @AndreiStefan I have updated the question. Can you please check once again

Comment: Do you have any annotations on your `UserServiceImplTest` class?

Comment: Well, you should, because there is no application context created.

Comment: Can you tell which annotation should be added.

Comment: Soemething like this: `@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:servlet.xml"} )
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)`. And under `locations` you need to place the path to your servlet.xml file.

Comment: If i user this service in my controller. do i need to use this annotation there?

Comment: `UserServiceImplTest` is a test class (probably with JUnit) and to make it work you need to tell Spring what xml file to use to build the application context your tests will use. Those two annotations are required for such a class to be able to execute successfully. I recommend reading the relevant section from the Spring reference documentation. Your controllers have nothing to do with your test class, that's a separate story.

Comment: @AndreiStefan Thanks. I'll read about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got an answer. Thanks @Andrei Stefan.

Because i am running a test, I have to annotate test like the below with your xml file path.

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml"})
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class UserServiceImplTest {

@Autowired
UserService userService;

@Test
public void shouldAddUser() {
    User user = new User("firstName", "lastName", new Date(), "M", "username", "password");
    userService.addUser(user);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Example usage for your hibernate;

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.base.package"/>
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<tx:annotation-driven/>
<context:annotation-config />

<bean id="_hibernateSessionFactory"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="configLocation" value="WEB-INF/hibernate.cfg.xml"/>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

 <!-- userDao Repo -->
    <bean id="_userDao"
        class="com.hemanths.expense.manager.hibernate.dao.impl.UserDaoImpl">
        <property name="_hibernateSessionFactory">
            <ref bean="_hibernateSessionFactory"></ref>
        </property>
    </bean>


 <!-- userService Repo -->
    <bean id="_userDao"
        class="com.hemanths.expense.manager.service.impl.UserServiceImpl">
        <property name="_hibernateSessionFactory">
            <ref bean="_hibernateSessionFactory"></ref>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Add hibernate class in your DaoImpl with getter and setter :

```
private SessionFactory _hibernateSessionFactory;
```

use autowire in your controller where you want :

```
@Autowired
private UserServiceImpl _userServiceImpl;
```

Answer (score 0):

As has been mentioned in the comments, you do not need to create beans for your service and DAO classes in your `servlet.xml` file:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd     http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.hemanths.expense.manager"/>
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<tx:annotation-driven/>
<context:annotation-config />

<bean id="sessionFactory"
  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
<property name="configLocation" value="WEB-INF/hibernate.cfg.xml"/>
<property name="hibernateProperties">
    <props>
        <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
    </props>
</property>
</bean>

</beans>
```

You also do not need to supply constructors for your service and DAO classes, because they are Spring components:

```
@Repository("userDao")
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    // Methods here

}


@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;

    // Methods here

}
```

Comment: Dont you need a getter and setter

Comment: I have removed and checked it still throws NullPointerException. I have updated the question. Please check

Comment: @HemanthGowda: Getter and setter for what?  When you autowire beans, you are implicitly setting them in your dependent class with the instance already created.  If can you post the code for your User class?  It is possible Hibernate is not correctly identifying and mapping your class.